# Excel Trick - For lookups

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to achieve the following as shown in screen shots. Is there any way I can use any trick in excel to achieve this very easily? As my data set is very large

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: @BigBen,  Thank you for editing my post

Comment: Power Query editor gets you there but it depends if you have that feature.  Unpivot the data, then add a column with formula to get the column header name then repivot based on the date.  Power use function   Data--> Get Data-->Launch Power query editor

Comment: @xQbert, is it possible to achieve this easily using Power BI? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry I'm not a Power BI user  So I don't know how hard/easy it would be.  If you can record it as a macro and PowerBI can open the excel doc run the macro....  I'm confident it can be done.  Not sure about the complexity.  Guess I should have asked if this is a one time thing or recurring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **Excel 365**-formula solution for your question:

I added a table `tblData` to the sheet - data are not 100 % equal to yours ... benefit of using a table: columns are addressed by their names not "abstract" A,B,C

[image]

Formulas in A13, B12 and B13 are spill formulas - so the size of new table depends on the data of the data source.

A13: `=tblData[Tool]` spills down with all tools

B12: `=LET(minDate,MIN(tblData[[ROM]:[EOP]]),maxDate,MAX(tblData[[ROM]:[EOP]]), SEQUENCE(1,maxDate-minDate+1,minDate))` spills to the right according to the date range from ROM and EOP column

B13: `=LET(rgROM,FILTER(tblData,(tblData[#Headers]="ROM")), rgEOP,FILTER(tblData,(tblData[#Headers]="EOP")), rowIndex,SEQUENCE(ROWS(rgROM)), IF(INDEX(rgEOP,rowIndex)=B12#,"EOP", IF(INDEX(rgROM,rowIndex)=B12#,"ROM","")))` checks if the date from row 12 equals to either the date in EOP or ROM - if yes the according value is written.

If you add rows or change the dates within ROM and EOP the result table will handle this.

Except for formatting the dates - this has to be done manually - esp. if the date range increases.

Format condition is not spilling - but has to be applied manually.
Maybe it's possible to enhance this too - but I haven't tried it.

`=AND(COLUMN()>=MATCH("EOP",$B13:$P13,0)+1,COLUMN()<=MATCH("ROM",$B13:$P13,0)+1)`
Please adjust the cell references to your needs

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am having problem with conditional formatting formula. It's giving me an error.

Comment: added the condition formula to the answer - please adjust the ranges according to your sheet.

Comment: Thank you for updating formula.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:**  Use the Power Query Editor feature.
Select desired data in a range:
right click and select get data from table/range... follow on screen instructions

**More specific steps :**

1.0) Select data; then right click select get data from table/range

2.0) From Power Query editor popup...

2.1) Select range to unpivot data.. (Shift and select 1st & last columns with dates)

2.2) goto transform unpivot columns

2.2.1) now you should have 3 columns

2.3 select the value column with dates

2.3.1 transform--> Pivot Column

2.3.2 from the popup have attribute as your values column

2.3.2.1 select advanced and select either min or max (it doesn't matter which)

2.4 select close and load.

[image]

[image]

If needed, record the above as a macro for repeated execution; but the steps are pretty straight forward once you learn them.

Comment: This was very efficient, I was finally able to done it right after you sent this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: One it's done once, you could; I believe; record a macro and have it play back for other datasets; but I'm not sure how this would integrate with your desire to use Powershell.